# HTML5 file ignore CSS

Tags: css, html

I just approached HTML and CSS.

I wrote a little HTML5 file and a CSS file, but my HTML doesn't get any info from CSS because nothing is styled.

I'm using Eclipse, there is a directory "WebContent" where there is the HTML file, and the CSS is in WebContent/WEB_INF/CSS/file.css.

HTML file:

```
<html lang="it">

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css" type="text/css">

        <title>Strumenti musicali</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Negozio di strumenti musicali">
        <meta name="keywords" content="strumenti, musicali, negozio">
        <meta name="author" content="Paolo">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
            <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
            <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
            <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
        </nav> 

    <h2>The title attribute</h2>

    <p title="I'm a tooltip">
        Mouse over this paragraph, to display the title attribute as a tooltip.
    </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

and the CSS file:

```
head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}

body:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: block;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I don't know how the CSS file has to be indicated, because the file .html is in the directory "WebContent"; The CSS file in `WebContent/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css`; The path I used is "`/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css`" and still doesn't work.

EDIT:

It seems to work on Chrome and Edge, but neither in Firefox, nor in Eclipse.

Comment: The URL of your CSS file is wrong?

Comment: CSS file path is wrong.

Comment: You're dealing with **relative** paths, meaning it is relative to the page which is requesting the information. If your .html page resides at `WebContent/WEB-INF` then your CSS `href` tag should be `href="CSS/NewFile.css"`

Comment: The file .html is in "WebContent";
The CSS file in WebContent/WEB-INF/CSS/file.css";
The path I used is "/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css"; still doesn't work.

Comment: Then try this ``href="./WebContent/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css"``

Comment: No, `href="./WebContent/WEB-INF/CSS/file.css"` doesn't work.

Comment: ``NewFile.css``, not ``file.css``, try that.

Comment: What Vladimir posted should work for you. If not, try `href="WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css"`, unless of course the filename you're telling us is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I used the name of the file, that is NewFile, sorry   for the miscomprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the path "/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css", that's to say a relative path from the html file to the css one.

Comment: Tried, but it seems that is not the path the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your CSS file is incorrect. Assure that the relative path and filename match that of your intended CSS file.

In your case the path specified in html file points to "NewFile.css" which does not match "file.css", as Blackbam has mentioned. Other issues exist in the directory names as well. Fixing this will fix your issue.

I would also add that StackOverflow is not intended as a website to debug your issues.

Comment: No, the path and the name are correct.
The CSS file is named "NewFile.css", it's in `WebContent/WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css`. The HTML file is in `WebContent/file.html`.
The URL in `href` is `href="WEB-INF/CSS/NewFile.css"`.

So everything is correct, but the background color is always white and not lightblue, and no other changes are applied.